# css right and left border of image go over top border

Tags: css-float, border, css

check this out
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jfIil/

css code

```
.xyz {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #DEDEE0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEE0;
    border-left: 1px solid #DEDEE0;
    border-top: 3px solid #73A784;
}
```

you see the top-left and top-right corners ? why is it like this ? and how can I fix it ?
**I'm talking about the the top border get "cutted" in the corners ...**
thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean that they have a slight angle? A little more clarification on the question would be good.

Comment: Code in the question please. Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-color: red blue green yellow;
  border-style: solid dashed dotted double;
  border-width: 20px 10px 5px 15px;
}
```

This will set different widths, border-color and border-style for each of the four borders.

In addition, each of those properties can be broken down even further with border-left-style, border-top-width, border-bottom-color, and so on.

[**Checkout the fiddle here to understand better**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/msqEB/)

```
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-color: red blue green yellow;
  border-style: solid dashed dotted double;
  border-width: 20px 10px 5px 15px;
}
```

[**Solution here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/tLaJW/)

css

```
.xyz {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    border-right: 20px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px -20px 0 0 red;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: what you want it to behave? I mean what output do you want?